# Не работает ORDER BY + Дубли

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach, order-by

Есть две таблицы:

Таблица **prod** с полями:
*id, name, reiting, cat*

Таблица **purchase** с полями:
*type, status, data, cat*

Пытаюсь получить данные из двух таблиц за один запрос и отсортировать по убыванию поля *reiting*:

```
function get_data($p1, $p2, $p3) {
    global $mysqliRead;
    $s = $mysqliRead->prepare('SELECT prod.name, prod.reiting, purchase.type FROM prod, purchase WHERE prod.cat=? AND purchase.cat=? AND purchase.status=? ORDER BY prod.reiting DESC');
    $s->bind_param('iii', $p1, $p2, $p3);
    $s->execute();
    $r = $s->get_result();
    $a = $r->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $r->free_result();
    $s->close();
    return $a;
}

$get_data = get_data($cat, $cat, $status);


foreach($get_data as $k) {
   echo $k['name'];
}

// Вывод
бананы
бананы
кокосы
кокосы
манго
манго
```

В итоге сталкиваюсь с двумя проблемами - это дублирование вывода в foreach (бананы, бананы, кокосы, кокосы, манго, манго) и не работает сортирвка ORDER BY *reiting*.

Как быть в данной ситуации и добиться недублированного вывода и сортировки???

Comment: чтобы выводить данные из двух таблиц, они должны быть каким-то образом логически связаны между собой. То есть в одной из таблиц, например, есть поле, указывающее на строку второй таблицы. У вас же тут какое-то чутка отфильтрованное декартово произведение.

Comment: *не работает сортировка ORDER BY reiting* Не верю. К тому же Вы даже не смотрите на это поле...

Comment: @teran, Отредактировал вопрос. Но нет того, что нужно. Подскажите какой запрос сформировать?

Comment: @Akina, что значит не смотрю? Я же запросил его из базы.

Comment: Напечатайте **все** поля, которые вы получаете, и приложите получающийся вывод **прямо в вопрос**. Все нужные для решения проблемы данные **должны быть прямо в вопросе**, иначе вопрос будет закрыт.

Comment: @Arasaki Вы запросили из базы, но не напечатали. Откуда вы знаете, какие там значения получились и что они не сортированы? А по сути да - вы не установили в выборке никакую связь между таблицами, из-за этого все проблемы.

Comment: @CrazyElf, дополнил вопрос

Comment: `reiting` и `type` тоже напечатайте, хотя уже и так всё понятно

Comment: @CrazyElf, а что именно понятно, можно мне подсказать?

Comment: Что нужно добавить условие, которое свяжет между собой поля этих двух таблиц